# Looping a query from previous result in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, user and leads.  My goal is to find users with leads having status 'completed' and 'idle', after that use that result to get all the leads for that user.  Here is my query

```
$sql = "SELECT u.id FROM users u LEFT JOIN leads l ON u.id = l.user_id WHERE l.status IN('completed', 'idle')";

...
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
...
$usersleads = array();
foreach ($result as $userId) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM leads where user_id = ". $userId;

    ...
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach ($results as $ul) {
       array_push($usersleads, $row);
    }
}
```

This works for small results.  But if data gets bigger this just crashed and I can understand it.  I am looking for a more efficient way to query the db.

**UPDATE**
I think I have found a solution.  Now only has two queries over all.

```
$sql = "SELECT u.id FROM users u LEFT JOIN leads l ON u.id = l.user_id WHERE l.status IN('completed', 'idle')";
...
$userResult = $stmt->fetchAll();
...

$userIds = [];
foreach ($userResult as $user) {
    $userIds[] = $user['id'];
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM leads where user_id IN('" . implode("','", $userIds) ."')";
...
$leadsResult = $stmt->fetchAll();
...

foreach ($userResult as &$lead) {
    $lead['date'] = $this->getDateForLead($lead['id'], $leadsResult);
    // add other fields to $userResult
}

...
public function getDateForLead($leadId, $leads)
{
    foreach($leads as $lead) {
       if ($leadId = $lead['id']) {
          return $lead['date'];
       }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with these leads, as you go on you will most likely find all users will have at least one 'completed' and therefore end up with all of the leads in the database.

Comment: I am not saving this to another table, if that's what you mean.  I am passing this to a variable which then gets converted to another format like csv, json, etc.. depending on what the user wants.

Comment: The important thing is that if you want to write a CSV/JSON, then do it in your inner loop, don't store a huge internal array and then write the array out as a second step.  Try and remove as many intermediate steps as you can in any code.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that is the reason why I am asking for help. basically that, how to remove those intermediate steps by making single query instead of loop.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT u.id FROM users u LEFT JOIN leads l ON u.id = l.user_id WHERE l.status IN('completed', 'idle');   and SHOW INDEX FROM users;  and SHOW INDEX FROM leads;  so we can see the magnitude of data you are dealing with.